# Is it possible to implement email read-receipts using OpenERP?

Tags: email, odoo

Does anyone know if it's possible to implement email read-receipts in Open ERP?

I'd like to use OpenERP to send invoices to customers, and we'd like to be able to track if the customer has received the email.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is possible with openerp ! The system is already able to send à mail to the customer and can read mails in an inbox.

You would have to modify the fetchmail module and implement the email read-receipts standard.

I hope this will help you !

Answer (score 1):

We are actually planning the development of an email analytics module that does what you describe and more (did the recipient click on a certain link, bounce-backs management,... similarly to what MailChimp does).
This development hasn't started yet so there is no ETA but there are internal discussions to have it certified.
__
Fabrice
OpenERP US

Comment: so did you develop this module? I am looking to implement something similar.

Comment: Hi Fabrice! 
checked module, looks really nice, couln't find Opened feature working. Does it work? I have opened sent mail but in OpenERP I still see opened 0.

Comment: Finally, did you do this feature?

Comment: Yes it's now part of Odoo (formerly OpenERP) in standard. Check https://www.odoo.com/page/email-marketing